# Render a youtube embed code in rails template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, html-parsing

I am trying to embed a youtube embed in a rails view

In the controller I have

```
@embed_code = '<iframe width="480" height="270" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/#{video_id}?frameborder="0"allowfullscreen"></iframe>'
```

I am failing to find a way to write this to the view effective escaping and making html safe and display it as `<%= @embed_code.html_safe %>`

If anyone can offer some advice I would appreciate it I have walked myself in circles and am well confused at this stage. As far as I see it is the second quotes around the params causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller:

```
@embed_code = %Q{<iframe.....#{video_id}..>...</iframe>}.html_safe
# or
@embed_code = ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer.new(%Q{<iframe.....#{video_id}..>...</iframe>})
```

View:

```
<%= @embed_code %>
```

Comment: this appears to format the iframe correctly but the #{video_id} doesn't work, does #{} work with single qoutes '' ?

Comment: no, #{} works with double quotes. In your case when string has so many other double quotes inside, you'd better to use %Q{}

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<%= raw @embed_code %>
```

The [`raw`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw) helper prevents Rails to automatically escape the html code in the view.

Comment: Does this not provide the same functionality as .html_safe ?

Answer (score 0):

I think `sanitize` maybe what you want

```
%= sanitize @article.body %>


def sanitize(html, options = {})
  self.class.white_list_sanitizer.sanitize(html, options).try(:html_safe)
end
```